Import stand alone project into Springboot with its own jars
I need to create a Springboot application (using maven) that has some REST endpoints and for the service layer incorporate an existing project (which is not a springboot app) as the data layer.
The second project uses myBatis and has a lot of classes and xml mappings that we would like to reuse for any other new project.
I have been able to import the second project into my new application and everything compiles (java 17), but when I go to run it Springboot tells me that every other class in the second project we have written has to be a bean which is fixable. However Springboot also complains about the second projects dependencies such as SqlSessionFactory which is a myBatis class that it too has to be a bean.
I would be grateful if anyone could explain whats going on here at runtime and some ideas on how to overcome this issue. Im sure that many others have been able to import an external project that uses its own jars into a Springboot application.
